# Swift: preventing double-tapping in tic tac toe?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tic tac toe game here and I need a way to disable tap gesture recognition on spaces that have been played so that on their turn, the user cannot just tap places that have been played.

I'm thinking some kind of if-else statement that goes something like

```
if plays[imageViewTapped.tag] == true {
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
```

The above does not work, so I need help. The code:

```
    var plays = [Int:Int]()
    var done = false


    var aiDeciding = false

    var ticTacImages = [UIImageView]()

for imageView in ticTacImages {

            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageClicked:"))

        }
    }

    //Gesture Reocgnizer method
    func imageClicked(reco: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        var imageViewTapped = reco.view as UIImageView

        println(plays[imageViewTapped.tag])
        println(aiDeciding)
        println(done)

        opening1.hidden = true
        opening2.hidden = true
        opening3.hidden = true

        if plays[imageViewTapped.tag] == nil && !aiDeciding && !done {
            setImageForSpot(imageViewTapped.tag, player:.UserPlayer)
        }

        checkForWin()
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user taps an empty space do your usual stuff and use:

```
imageView.removeGestureRecognizer(myGestureRecognizer)
```

That should prevent any interaction with 'used' spaces in the tic tac toe grid.

Comment: So I put `ticTacImages[spot].removeGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer)` in my `setImageForSpot` function and I get the error "(UITapGestureRecognizer).type is not convertible to 'UIGestureRecognizer'"

Comment: Try something like this: let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageClicked:") then add the gesture with: imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap) and remove it with: imageView.removeGestureRecognizer(tap)

Comment: Alright so I put `let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageClicked:")
ticTacImages[spot].removeGestureRecognizer(tap)` in my function and there are no errors but it hasn't fixed the problem