# Swift: prevent tic tac toe double tap?

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a tic tac toe game here in Swift and I need a way to disable tap gesture recognition on spaces that have been played so that on their turn, the user cannot just tap places that have been played.

I have tried putting the line

```
ticTacImages[spot].removeGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageClicked:"))
```

in my `imageClicked` and `setImageForSpot` functions and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

The code involved:

```
for imageView in ticTacImages {

            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageClicked:"))

        }
    }

    //Gesture Reocgnizer method
    func imageClicked(reco: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        var imageViewTapped = reco.view as UIImageView

        println(plays[imageViewTapped.tag])
        println(aiDeciding)
        println(done)

        opening1.hidden = true
        opening2.hidden = true
        opening3.hidden = true

        if plays[imageViewTapped.tag] == nil && !aiDeciding && !done {
            setImageForSpot(imageViewTapped.tag, player:.UserPlayer)
            }

        checkForWin()

        let delay = 1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        //During delay
        for imageView in ticTacImages {
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        //After delay
        for imageView in self.ticTacImages {
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        self.aiTurn()
        })

    }
 var varChanger: Int?
    var playerMark: String?

    func setImageForSpot(spot:Int,player:Player){
        if varChanger == 1 {
            playerMark = player == .UserPlayer ? "blue_x" : "blue_o"
        }
        else if varChanger == 2 {
            playerMark = player == .UserPlayer ? "green_x" : "green_o"
        }
        else if varChanger == 3 {
            playerMark = player == .UserPlayer ? "purple_x" : "purple_o"
        }
        else if varChanger == 4 {
            playerMark = player == .UserPlayer ? "pink_x" : "pink_o"
        }
        else if varChanger == 5 {
            playerMark = player == .UserPlayer ? "yellow_x" : "yellow_o"
        }
        else {
            playerMark = player == .UserPlayer ? "red_x" : "red_o"
        }


        println("setting spot \(player.toRaw()) spot \(spot)")
        plays[spot] = player.toRaw()

        ticTacImages[spot].image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift: preventing double-tapping in tic tac toe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247637/swift-preventing-double-tapping-in-tic-tac-toe)

Answer (score 2):

You can only `removeGestureRecognizer()` for a gesture recognizer that has already been added. In your example you're creating a new one before removing it — instead you should keep track of the old one, or call `ticTacImages[spot].gestureRecognizers` to get an array of the ones which have been added.

Comment: That isn't working; its throwing an error with the (). Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, it's a property. Don't use `()`.

Comment: I get an error saying it resolves to an unused l-value

Comment: It is indeed an [lvalue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)). Read the UIView documentation — `gestureRecognizers` is an array. You can remove the recognizers which are in the array. If you need information about for loops and other such constructs, they are available in the standard Apple documentation.